# how to send a join request to a group? In my case i want connection requests to be sent to a group called mca

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

the record connection gets updated but then the value of mca_id is nil. Why is that ? I tried several things like rewriting the create function an everything, but nothing seems to happen . I'd really appreciate some help cuz I've spent quite sometime on this.

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :connection
  has_one :mca, through: :connection
end
```

Mca model:

```
class Mca < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :connections
  has_many :users, through: :connections
end
```

Connections model:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :mca


end
```

Connections controller:

```
class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /connections
  # GET /connections.json
  def index
    @connections = Connection.all
  end

  # GET /connections/1
  # GET /connections/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /connections/new
  def new
    @connection = current_user.build_connection(connection_params)
  end

  # GET /connections/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /connections
  # POST /connections.json
  def create
    @mca=Mca.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @connection = current_user.build_connection(:mca_id=> @mca , approved: false)

      if @connection.save
        flash[:notice] = "Connection requested."
        redirect_to :back
      else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to request connection."
        redirect_to :back
      end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /connections/1
  # PATCH/PUT /connections/1.json
  def update
    @mca=Mca.find(params[:mca_id])
    @connection= Connection.where(user_id: params[:id], mca_id: mca.id)
    @connection.update(approved: true)
     if @connection.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Successfully confirmed connection"
      else
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Sorry! Could not confirm connection!"
      end
  end

  # DELETE /connections/1
  # DELETE /connections/1.json
  def destroy
    @mca=Mca.find(params[:mca_id])
    @connection= Connection.where(user_id: params[:id], mca_id: @mca.id)
    @connection.destroy
    flash[:notice]= "Removed Connection"
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_connection
      @connection = Connection.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def connection_params
      params.require(:connection).permit(:user_id, :mca_id, :approved)
    end
end
```

my routes.rb has :

```
resources :connections
```

my views/mcas/show.html.erb has:

```
<p><%= link_to "Join", connections_path(:mca_id=>@mca) , :method=>:post , class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the create action of your ConnectionsController you have:

```
@mca=Mca.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Yet you're passing the parameter `mca_id` on your link_to, not `id` ... I assume what you want is:

```
@mca=Mca.find_by_id(params[:mca_id])
```

Comment: I'm new to rails.Could you kindly tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: well you appear to be passing `mca_id` but never accessing it? surely you just need `@mca=Mca.find_by_id(params[:mca_id])` ? but to be honest it's quite hard to understand the question as it's full of domain specific language.

Comment: Mike thank you :) Somehow I feel like I did try this earlier, but seemed to evade. Clearly I lacked something. Thanks for the response. I'm new on stackoverflow. I'll be on 15 rep points and upvote your answer :)

Comment: typically when an answer solves your problem, you mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick.